# C# async Task<string> result as System.Threading.Tasks.Task 1[System.String]

Tags: c#

I'm trying to return a link result to get from another class but don't quite understand Task<>.
Where i'm trying to get the result from is in another class

Looked online for answers but didn't really find anything useful apart from when I found out Task could be useful and this is my current stage, now it's 2:40am and I'm confused

```
    public static async Task<string> ImgurUpload()
    {
        ImgurImage streamImage = null;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes("test.png")))
        {
            streamImage = await AO023ASD.UploadImageAnonymous(ms, "1", "2", "3");
        }
        return streamImage.Link;
    }
```

I expect the output of a url: e.g www.urlresult.com/123123.png but the actual output is System.Threading.Tasks.Task1[System.String]

Comment: How are you calling the above function? Do you have an await in front of it?

Comment: The output of the method is `Task<string>` - the use of `async` in the signature does not change what type a calling method sees. The only thing that changes is that the `return` within the method automatically gets a `Task<>` wrapped around the value that it's trying to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function returns a `Task<String>`.  If you want the output of the `Task`, you need to wait for the `Task` to finish and then get the result from the object.  This might look like:

```
var task = ImgurUpload();
task.Wait();
Console.WriteLine(task.Result);
```

If your calling method is also `async`, you would probably prefer to `await task` - this way your calling method will also pause its execution until the Task is complete and give control back to its caller.  `await` returns the result of the task automatically.

```
var task = ImgurUpload();
Console.WriteLine(await task);
```

Alternatively, if you don't actually need your method to be asynchronous, you can immediately wait for the result of the image upload and keep your method synchronous:

```
public static string ImgurUpload()
{
    ImgurImage streamImage = null;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes("test.png")))
    {
        streamImage = AO023ASD.UploadImageAnonymous(ms, "1", "2", "3")
                              .GetAwaiter().GetResult(); //This gives the same result as using
                                                         //.Wait() and .Result, but in one line
    }
    return streamImage.Link;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I didn't think of your second method!